# How ASP.NET team generates *.Designer.cs-files from *.resx-files in MVC 6 project?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

How Microsoft developers generates `*.Designer.cs`-files from `*.resx`-files in http://github.com/aspnet/mvc project?

Answer (score 6):

The magic is in this Shade file: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/dev/build/_k-generate-resx.shade that is imported by each project through the `KoreBuild` package.

If you run our build commands (`build.cmd` or `build.sh`) and pass the argument `resx` - e.g. `build.cmd resx` - all the `resx` files will be parsed and the `*.designer.cs` regenerated.

PS: this works for any ASP.NET project under https://github.com/aspnet , including MVC